# обработка строки-списка json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, list

Есть строка по типу (именно строка, не список):

```
[{"name1":"age1"},{"name2":"age2"},{"name3":"age3"}]
```

что то не могу сообразить как разбить эту строку на отдельные json и с каждым работать- split по запятой не подходит ибо в json может быть запятая.
Подскажите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Модуль *json* к вашим услугам:

```py
import json

# some JSON:
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y["age"])
```

Или же работа с файлами:

```py
import json

with open("file.json", encoding="utf_8") as json_file:
    data = json.loads(json_file)
```

Подробнее [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал так: `with open("file.json", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:`. `"r"` по умолчанию используется, поэтому можно не указывать, а в `open` если не указывать кодировку, будет системная

Comment: json это хорошо, но тут у меня строка, в которой несколько обьектов json, а не один {"name1":"age1"},{"name2":"age2"},{"name3":"age3"}, как обратиться например к name2?

Comment: Очень странно, что эта библиотека не может работать с множеством json
Я вижу только способ regex'ом выдрать 1 объект

Comment: Вот что-то типа этого - https://pastebin.com/TksZeCw4